Installing ubuntu failed after selecting "try and install ubuntu"
I am trying to install ubuntu on my newly built PC but so far I always stuck at the booting phase.
here is what I have done

Install windows

free some space (500GiB) for ubuntu

download ubuntu desktop here https://ubuntu.com/desktop

use rufus to create a bootable usb drive

disable secure boot and fastboot

restart my pc and use f12 to choose boot from the usb drive

I saw the screen for selecting different booting option e.g. try and install ubuntu, graphic safe mode etc

Then after select try and install ubuntu I saw this screen stuck screen then the process just hangs there for ever


few thing I tried,

connecting monitor to motherboard video output same thing
tried the graphics safe mode, same thing

my build
gigabyte x870 motherboard
9800x3d
gigabyte 4060 gpu

This question would be best asked on AskUbuntu.
